# How to use 'expect' to automatically answer prompts in shell file?

Tags: shell, expect

I've .sh file which will throw some prompts and I want expect to answer those prompts to so script can run successfully.
here is a file contents :

```
echo Enter your name
read name
echo $name
echo Enter your age
read age
echo $age
```

I want 'expect' to answer this prompts with predefined input I provide.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Where exactly are you stuck? I guess you are by and large familiar with *expect*; if not, you should study [some examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) first.

Comment: If you control how the script is written, you should be writing it to be able to collect input via an alternate mechanism and not require either interactive or real simulated input. For instance, prompting only if environment variables or command-prompt parameters weren't set with the data you want is a common approach.

Comment: ie. `[ -n "$name" ] || { echo "Enter your name"; read name; }` will only read the name if it's not already given. If you run `name="Siddharth" ./yourscript`, then it'll get the name via its environment and not need to prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need expect for this:

```
printf "%s\n" "my name" "my age" | ./myscript.sh
```

Or, if your shell is sh/ksh/bash/zsh

```
./myscript.sh <<END
my name
my age
END
```